# How to detect auto-generated method parameters on service proxies?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, proxy

When I create a proxy to my service, some extra parameters are added as XmlIgnoreAttribute. For example:

Interface method contract declaration:

```
[OperationContract]
void AddToList(int integerToAdd);
```

Method implementation:

```
public void AddToList(int integerToAdd) {
    intList.Add(integerToAdd);
}
```

Now, here is what this method actually looks like when I generate a proxy to my service dynamically:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/IService1/AddToList", RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
public void AddToList(int integerToAdd, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()] bool integerToAddSpecified)
{
    this.Invoke("AddToList", new object[] {integerToAdd, integerToAddSpecified});
}
```

If I have the ParameterInfo object for this parameter, how can I check that this parameter has been marked as XmlIgnoreAttribute?

If this is not a good way to check for these auto-generated parameters, then is there another (better) way to check for them?

Bonus: Will there ever be a case where non-boolean types are generated and marked as XmlIgnoreAttribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you would use [ParameterInfo.GetCustomAttributes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kk93tbd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) ?

```
ParameterInfo secondParam = ..
object[] attribs = 
          secondParam.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlIgnoreAttribute), false);
//the second bool param is ignored. See the docs.
//check if => attribs has anything..
```

**(1)** I'm not sure why you're checking these parameters anything so not sure if it's good/better. **(2)** Not sure about the second question. I assume this is from VS code gen (`svcutil`?) Maybe some MSFT's who's designed this may know better.

Comment: I am invoking the method, and the boolean is a required parameter that I need to set to true when I set the integer, so I wanted to find a way to detect this type of attribute and set it. Thanks. I found it on the custom attributes, but, that being said, do you have anything on the bonus question? *LOL* Are only generated boolean types marked as XmlIgnoreAttribute?

Comment: @Alexandru thats what I meant in my answer after `(2)`. You may have better luck hunting down some guys from MS team that built svcutil or someone who knows someone, and email them. I've done this many times and if you're thorough it works out :D